# Rationale for behaviour overriding a val

Tags: scala, overriding, lazy-evaluation

```
class A { 
  val x = println("A") 
}
class B extends A {
  override val x = println("B")
}
(new B).x
```

Prints:

```
A
B
```

However,

```
class A { 
  lazy val x = println("A") 
}
class B extends A {
  override lazy val x = println("B")
}
(new B).x
```

Prints just:

```
B
```

[According to Martin Odersky](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Overriding-val-and-initialization-td1951394.html), the behaviour, at least in the non-lazy case, is "as specified". I'm curious as to why the behaviour is specified that way, and why it differs when the val is lazy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code in the template ("body") of a class definition, outside of member definitions, is what goes into the constructor. Constructors for parent classes are always called when you initialize an instance of a child class (in this case, you are calling a constructor with no arguments, otherwise the syntax would be `class B extends A(arg1, arg2) { ... }`). For more details, see Section 5.1 in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

That is why `println("A")` is evaluated in the first case; that `val` definition is part of the constructor code.

When you think about what happens at construction time in the second example, you never asked for the value of `x` defined in `A`; now because it is a `lazy val`, it will not be computed before it is needed.

You can think of `lazy val`s as methods that take no argument and that cache their output the first time they are called. You didn't call that method here, you just defined it.

Comment: Also note that: `(1)` class A { lazy val x: Int = throw new IllegalStateException("AAA"); val z = x; println(z) } `(2)` class B extends A { override lazy val x = 5 } `(3)` (new B) prints 5, no exception is thrown, since lazy val access is indeed method call (of the overridden method).

Answer (score 1):

```
class A { 
  val x = println("A") 
}
class B extends A {
  override val x = println("B")
}
(new B).x
```

During the execution of the constructor, all the initializations of `val`s (and other statements) are executed. Therefore, `val x = println("A")` is run as part of the construction of `A` and `override val x = println("B")` is run as part of the construction of `B`. They both print some string and initialize `x` to `()` (of type `Unit`), so override is just a red herring here. The `.x` (from `(new B).x`) does nothing.

In the lazy case, you're initializing `x` to something like a function taking no arguments and returning `Unit`. It is not run till you read `.x`, and, since `x` is overridden, only "B" gets printed in that case.